# How to use contact_ws in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

This is the `$query` configuration that I have:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->select("concat_ws(' ', m.first_name, m.last_name) full_name")->from('members m')->orderBy('full_name')->all();
```

When I open in browser it appear error:

```
The SQL being executed was: SELECT concat_ws(' ', `m`.`first_name`, `m`.`last_name)` AS `full_name` FROM `members` `m`ORDER BY `full_name`
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please explain better .. i don't understand what's the issue to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this array notation

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())->
  select(["concat_ws(' ', m.first_name, m.last_name) AS full_name"])->
  from('members m')->
  orderBy('full_name')->all();
```